# Removing Package Error

Tags: read-only

Error shown on terminal:

```
sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/jianyue/0: Read-only file system
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

if you need more infos, please help.

Comment: Please provide the output of the following command: `mount | grep "^/dev"`. Just to check if your filesystem is mounted read-only

Comment: I have pasted the command you have told me to perform. Here is the result : /dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)

Comment: Try this: `cat /proc/mounts`. And if you can please use http://paste.ubuntu.com/ to post output results.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your reply. I have done what you told me to do. Here is the link : http://paste.ubuntu.com/1334320/ .

Comment: Your Ubuntu was installed in Windows (using Wubi)?

Comment: No, my ubuntu is not installed with windows, I dual boot it. I didn't use Wubi.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your terminal

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I got this error : sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/jianyue/0: Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/dpkg/lock': Read-only file system
after I ran the command.